# UISplitViewController that is not rootViewController

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

Yes, I know Apple doesn't want to do that, but I want to do.

I want to use another `UISplitViewController` as modal view controller.

I found some solutions by googling,

1. make your own `UISplitViewController`

   yes! it's simple and some already implemented it.
2. use one `UISplitViewController`, and change its `viewControllers` property

   `viewControllers` property have to managed by stack, like UINavigationController does.
3. make another `UIViewController`, and assign its view property that is from UISplitViewController

   I made `MyViewController`, and it has `UISplitViewController` instance from nib (or code)

   in `viewDidLoad` in `MyViewController`:

   ```
   self.view = splitViewController.view
   ```

   and I'm using `MyViewController` as modal view controller.

   It shows `UISplitViewController` well, but `UISplitViewControllerDelegate` doesn't work because it is not root view controller.

any more suggestions, or which way do you recommend, friends?

Comment: You can use a UISplitViewController as a modal view controller, because it will be the root of a new navigation stack (or it will be the only view controller), you might just have to use UIModalPresentationFullScreen.

Comment: According to this [answer][1] it is not possibly using Interface Builder.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12307948/593214

Answer (score 0):

I just found the following, which seems to solve my main problem (being able to use a split view as child of a navigation controller):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/307008/Versatile-programmer-friendly-split-view-controlle

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, I know Apple doesn't want to do that, but I want to do.

Why do you want to, if you don't have to? :)

If you are still looking for a simpler approach, please check out my answer on this [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19983002/1134595)..