# iOS: perform segue to Split view controller doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, ios

Hi i have a master detail application and trying to perform segue from the detail view to a new split view controller.  I've tried many times and it still didn't work.

The action that performs the below code is from a navigation bar button at the detail page.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DetailsToSettings" sender:self];
```

I think it's suppose to be pretty simple, but it doesn't work for some reasons.

Comment: Did you set the segue in Storyboard?

Comment: Yes. DetailsToSettings was set in the identifier.

Comment: Does your action gets called? Did you set the action in the Storyboard?

Comment: forget it, i just figure you can't use split view controller in other places either than being the root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

goodness....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044586/storyboard-uiviewcontroller-and-uisplitviewcontroller

Split view controller can't be used either than being the root view controller in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to segue to a split view controller by embedding it in a navigation controller and then segueing modally to that in a storyboard. I don't know what Apple thinks of this though...