# Transition not showing between views in a custom UIStoryboardSegue

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uistoryboardsegue, uiviewanimationtransition

I have written a custom UIStoryboardSegue.

The only code in my CustomSegue.m file is:

```
-(void) perform {
    UIViewController* sourceViewController = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController* destinationViewController = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;

    UIWindow* window = UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow;
    window.rootViewController = destinationViewController;
    window.rootViewController = sourceViewController;    

    [UIView transitionWithView: sourceViewController.view.window
                        duration: 0.5
                         options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                      animations: ^{window.rootViewController = destinationViewController;}
                      completion: ^(BOOL finished) {}
     ];
}
```

If I set up a storyboard so it just has two UIViewControllers, with a button on the first linking to the second, all works as planned: there is a flip from left transition.

But: if I place a UINavigationController before the first UIViewController, the segue now brings up the second view controller without doing a flip from left.

What is going on? Why doesn't the transition work with a navigation controller?

Thanks for your help!

(In case you're interested, the reason I'm using a custom segue is so that I can have a master-detail view appearing after some intro pages. I am inspired by [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044586/storyboard-uiviewcontroller-and-uisplitviewcontroller#answer-12730697).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never resolved this, but found a simple workaround. I removed the navigation controller from the front, but put one after the segue instead. I then put a simple navigation bar at the top of the source screen. The segue also triggered adding a back button to the destination view controller. My custom segue thus became a "pseudo push" segue.