# Navigate between UISplitViewController and UIViewControllers

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, ios7.1, xcode5.1

> I have a `UISplitViewController` which I have set as
>   `rootViewController` in `appDelegate`.But before displaying
>   `UISplitViewController`,there are two `UIViewControllers`. When the app
>   starts,there will be `UIViewController` one after another.Then from
>   second `UIViewController`,it will navigate to `UISplitViewController`.
>   Now,it is simple to display `UISplitViewController` from
>   UIViewControllers, but problem arises when i want to display
>   `UIViewController` from `UISplitViewController`. Means,unable to navigate
>   between `UIViewControllers` and `UISplitViewController`. I have checked
>   every solution.I also tried to `presentViewController` but it just
>   failed. Please help me. It would be great pleasure to get solution
>   from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this link.According to your question i too tried like this before after that i googled and i got this solution.

[How to create a segue from UIViewController to a UISplitViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812942/how-to-create-a-segue-from-uiviewcontroller-to-a-uisplitviewcontroller)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @user3698223. I have tried this code.I am adding `UISplitViewController` same like this.But the problem is that I can't Pop back from `UISplitViewController` to `UIViewController`. As you said ,you were having same problem then how did you pop to `UIViewController` from `UISplitViewController`?.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue.I resolved this problem by putting whole project in `UISplitViewController` and then hiding/Unhiding the `masterViewController`. Here is the code to hide the `MasterViewController`.  Firstly using `UISplitViewController's` `Delegate` method

```
- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
      return YES;
}
```

then declare this  `BOOL masterIsHidden;` under implementation then add the following method

```
-(void)hideMaster:(BOOL)hideState
{
    masterIsHidden=hideState;
    [self.splitViewController.view setNeedsLayout];
    self.splitViewController.delegate = nil;
    self.splitViewController.delegate = self;
    [self.splitViewController willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation duration:0];
}
```

and call this above method in `viewWillAppear` like this

```
[self hideMaster:YES];
```

Using this method you can hide/Unhide `masterViewController` anywhere in your project.